# How can I place some of my Node.js files outside of my Node.js application root folder?

Tags: node.js

I want to put my Node unit tests in an application root level folder, `/test/server/`. The problem is that when I put my Node files there, Node doesn't see my `node_modules`. My Node app is at `/server/`.

My app folder is structured like this:

```
|- server/ (where my Node.js stuff is)
| |- package.json
| |- server.js
| |- etc
|- client/ (where my AngularJS and front-side stuff are)
| |- index.jade
| |- CSS/
| |- etc
|- test/ (where my unit tests are)
| |- server/
| |- client/
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set node path in your environment

NODE_PATH="/path/to/node_modules"

then you should be able to reference them

**EDIT:** Now that I had a second look at your require statement I see that you are specifying an extension for the module you are trying to require, remove that and you should be able to find the module

Comment: I made a file called `test-config.js` inside my `/test/server/` folder. I put `process.env.NODE_PATH = '../../server/node_modules'; var expect = require('expect.js');` and I tried to run the file `node test-config.js` but I still got error `Cannot find module 'expect.js'`. This module becomes visible if I put `tests-config.js` inside `/server/`.

Comment: did you install your modules using 'npm' ?

Comment: Yes, I installed them with `npm`.

Comment: forget what I said before about the path... just remove ".js" from the require statement so it looks like this **require("expect");**

Comment: In `expect.js`, `.js` is not the extension of the file, it's part of the name of this module, which is installed with npm like `npm install expect.js`.

Comment: when you require a module in your test-config.js you do not need to specify '.js' in the require statement. So instead of writing "require('expect.js')" do "require('expect')"

Comment: @DmitryMatveev I actually prefer to specify extension when I require individual files. Reasons: 1) it's indication to me that I'm requering file, not a module 2) you might require wrong file (I spend 10 minutes debugging error caused by having 'file.js' and 'file.json', I expected result of file.json) 3) it's faster 4) You get less exceptions which make use breakOnException in debugger easier

Comment: Why not move package.json to the same level where you have server, client and test folders?

Comment: he is requiring a module, putting a '.js' in such a case causes the module not found error which is exactly what is he doing wrong

Comment: @AndreySidorov Moving `package.json` and `node_modules` out of `/server/` and to the top worked for me! @DmitryMatveev `.js` is not optional in this case. See the instructions on the [project page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js/) on GitHub.